# In intellij I want to create a button that will open a specifc pdf file

Tags: android, pdf, sd-card

I am looking to create an app that has a brief detail about a product, then on the click of the button on that app page it takes you to a detailed brochure or manual stored on the sd card.

1. need an intent to open a pdf from the sd card
2. ideally the same intent, but different file locations defined with the associated button.

I can get a button  to do something onclick, but don't know how to do the open the pdf file from sd card using adobe reader.

I would be grateful for a solution, or a link to a tutorial so I progress, but everything I have read doesn't quite fit. In the meantime I will keep searching.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am looking to create an app that has a brief detail about a product, then on the click of the button on that app page it takes you to a detailed brochure or manual stored on the sd card.

Since you do not have much access to [removable storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html), I sincerely hope that by "sd card", you mean [external storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html).

> need an intent to open a pdf from the sd card

Use:

```
new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
  .setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(filePointingToYourPdf), "application/pdf");
```

with `startActivity()`.

> but don't know how to do the open the pdf file from sd card using adobe reader.

Since the user does not necessarily have "adobe reader", just call `startActivity()` with the aforementioned `Intent`, where `filePointingToYourPdf` is a `File` object pointing to the PDF to view.

> but everything I have read doesn't quite fit

In the future, when using Stack Overflow, please explain what you tried and why it "doesn't quite fit". We cannot help you with that if you do not tell us what it is.

Comment: wrt to internal storage Device memory? 16GB  and a seperate SD card 64GB the files to be stored somwhere within the 60Gb that are left

Comment: @MadWayne: As noted in the blog post that I linked to, starting with Android 4.4, you no longer have direct access to removable media. You are welcome to attempt to find your in the `MediaStore` `ContentProvider`, then use the `Uri` you get from `MediaStore` with your `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent`.

Comment: sorted working with :-button18.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

File file =new File("/storage/extSdCard/abc.pdf");
                Intent passIntent;
                passIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                    .setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");
                startActivity(passIntent);
            }});  just need to tweak the new file for each button but think I will be able to do that, Thanks again

Comment: struggling with getting my head around the intent calling a different file, at the moment File file =new File(path+"bcd.pdf"); where bcd.is the bit that changes for any given button, t the moment its just written out in full with the file name changed, dont want to write it in full..... hopefully get it today at some point